How to delay updates in sortable table header, so screen reader can read all?
What are good ways to slow down the provision of new information in a sortable table, with up to two sorting criteria in two lists of a table column, on a website, so that e.g. the NVDA screen reader has enough time to read out all updates?
[1] https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/table/examples/sortable-table/
// delays all setTimeout calls by an additional 2 seconds
(function() {
    const originalSetTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    window.setTimeout = function(callback, delay) {
        return originalSetTimeout(callback, delay + 2000);
    };
})();


I believe the scope of this is going to be much greater than just a delay here - there are a lot of related questions with cover differing parts of what you ask; you have to consider the complexity of what is being read and at the end make what will perhaps be a "guess" on how much time to delay - for example some readers let the user slow down the reading and you likley won't be able to easily detect that.
